# Printing value of specific key of an object in angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to access a value of specific key but getting all the values in the object. I just need to print value of key name. How will I do it ?

"currencies": { "code": "ALL", "name": "Albanian lek", "symbol": "L" }

The following line is printing all the values.

```
 <div  *ngFor="let item of data.currencies | keyvalue">
        {{item.value}}
    </div>
```

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your question?

Answer (score 0):

You were just about there

```
export class AppComponent  {
  data = {
     "currencies": { 
       "code": "ALL", "name": "Albanian lek", "symbol": "L" }
  }
}
```

All key/values

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data.currencies | keyvalue">
   {{item.key}}: {{item.value}}
</div>
```

Single value from key

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data.currencies | keyvalue">
   <div *ngIf="item.key === 'name'">{{item.key}}: {{item.value}}</div>
</div>
```

More than one key

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data.currencies | keyvalue">
   <div *ngIf="['name','symbol'].includes(item.key)">{{item.key}}: {{item.value}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

First (and most efficient way) you have array of `keys` you want to show them then you can do like this:

Go through of your keys and print out the value.

```
  currencies = { code: 'ALL', name: 'Albanian lek', symbol: 'L' };
  somKeys = ['code', 'name']

  <div *ngFor="let key of somKeys">
     {{currencies[key]}}
  </div>
```

The second way is that go through all `currencies` and use `*ngIf` to determine which value must be show.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of currencies | keyvalue">
  <div *ngIf="item.key === 'code' || item.key === 'name'">{{item.value}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I ran this code and everything was OK? Please share some more details about your project